# dynamically generating cmake CMakeLists.txt to match the nuget package content

Tags: c++, linux, cmake, nuget, native

I'm porting some existing (c++) Visual Studio projects to linux that leverage native nuget packages. The linux projects use cmake and the CMakeLists.txt file will either be hand generator or converted from the vs project file using a conversion tool like cmake-convertor. nuget package information is stored in package.config files and installed directly per cmake with a nuget install option within the CMakeLists.txt.
My dilemma is defining the compile and link information for each installed nuget package, as each one could follow its own convention where headers reside, additional lib dependencies, etc. On windows, this information is stored in .targets file, which is also part of the nuget package. Is there a way to parse this file when cmake runs?

Comment: Depending on the package you may want to consider using `vcpkg` and start with `CMake` on both platforms. `vcpkg` can generate `nuget` packages if those are still desired.

Comment: CMake on Wins is a future consideration. Not familiar with vcpkg, will look into it.

Comment: Unable to figure out how to use vcpkg to install a nuget package from my local nuget source for centos 7.

Comment: You can't do that. I meant to use `vcpkg` on both sides. If you you need `nuget` packages on windows you can have it generate them. However all of this depends on what packages you are using and if they are in the thousands of ports that are supported. Obviously your own code will not be suported.

Comment: Our packages are homegrown, private nuget packages that will consist of binaries usable crossplatform.

Comment: vcpkg will not really help with that. Sorry.